# How To Fix Out Of Bounds UIButtons In Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I've used a navigation controller to place uibuttons and these are the problems

1. The buttons are out of bounds
2. The navigation bar doesn't show up even though I set 
   `navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false`
   I've also attached a screenshot showing the output of the code

   ```
   private func setupnavigationBarItems() {
     //menu button
     let mb = UIButton(type: .system)
     mb.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
        "menu").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
     mb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuclicked) , for: 
        .touchUpInside)
     mb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     mb.frame = CGRect()
     view.addSubview(mb)
     mb.anchors(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, topPad: 0, 
         bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, bottomPad: 0, 
         left: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, leftPad: 10, 
         right: nil, rightPad: 0, height: 30, width: 30)


     //search button(right). place this in an array and use it for 
        user search function
     let searchButton = UIButton(type: .system)
     searchButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
        "search").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
     searchButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchController), 
         for: .touchUpInside)
     searchButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     searchButton.frame = CGRect()
     view.addSubview(searchButton)
     searchButton.anchors(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, 
          topPad: 0, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, 
          bottomPad: 0, left: nil, leftPad: 0, right: 
          view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, rightPad: 5, height: 
          30, width: 30)

     //compose button,search button placed in array
     let composeButton = UIButton(type: .system)
     composeButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
       "6").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
     composeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLogout), 
          for: .touchUpInside)
     searchButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     composeButton.frame = CGRect()
     view.addSubview(composeButton)
     composeButton.anchors(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, 
          topPad: 0, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, 
          bottomPad: 5, left: nil, leftPad: 0, right: 
          view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, rightPad: 2, height: 
          30, width: 30)

     //array of buttons
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = 
          [UIBarButtonItem(customView: composeButton), 
          UIBarButtonItem(customView:searchButton)]
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = 
     [UIBarButtonItem(customView: mb)]
     navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
     navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
   }
   ```

[image: screenshot of problem]

Answer (score 0):

To fix your navigation bar issues, you'll want to make your viewcontroller to be the root view controller for a navigation controller [image]

Drag a navigation controller on to your storyboard, drag over the arrow coming in from the left onto the navigation controller and control click the navigation controller onto the view controller.

As for the buttons, I'm not sure what you want to do. If they're supposed to be in the navigation bar, you'll want to add them to the viewController's navigationItem, either to the rightBarButtonItems or to the leftBarButtonItems.

Answer (score 0):

For the navigation bar not showing up issue, please make sure your view controller is a child of some UINavigationController.

Regarding the buttons assuming that you want them to show up in the UINavigationBar, you don't need them to be added as a subview into your "view" and the constraints are also irrelevant. You can initialise your buttons and add them to UINavigationBarItem left or right bar button items. The same can be done through Storyboard also. Let me know if you want more inputs.